# Как запустить окно без контрольных кнопок и не отображать его в панели задач?

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу приложение, окно которого нужно отобразить без контрольных кнопок для этого использую

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

и без отображения его на панели задач для этого использую

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

Но вмести из них работает что то одно с помощью чего можно добиться этих свойств у окна ?

Comment: Хорошего способа нет, насколько я понял. Предлагают костыли: сделать главное окно `UTILITY` и как-нибудь его спрятать, а приложение показывать в дочернем окне (`UNDECORATED`). Можете посмотреть варианты кода на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564136/javafx-can-you-create-a-stage-that-doesnt-show-on-the-task-bar-and-is-undecora?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @defaultlocale Да это то что нужно если нет прямого решения,  поставте пожалуйста в ответ, только подробней распишите о создании дочернего окна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, удобного способа добиться такого поведения нет.

В ответах [на похожий вопрос в английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564136/javafx-can-you-create-a-stage-that-doesnt-show-on-the-task-bar-and-is-undecora?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) предлагают различные костыли: например, сделать главное окно `UTILITY` и как-нибудь его спрятать, а приложение показывать в дочернем окне (`UNDECORATED`).

Спрятать главное окно можно задвинув его за края экрана с помощью [`Window.setX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setX-double-), либо сделав его полностью прозрачным, с помощью [`Window.setOpacity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOpacity-double-).

Пример кода:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    //проставляем у главного окна стиль UTILITY
    //чтобы не отображалось в панели задач
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    //делаем главное окно полностью прозрачным
    primaryStage.setOpacity(0);
    //показываем
    primaryStage.show();

    //содержимое будет отражаться во втором, дочернем окне
    Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
    secondaryStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
    //дочернему окну проставляем стиль TRANSPARENT
    //чтобы скрыть служебные кнопки
    secondaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    //заполняем и показываем дочернее окно 
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getChildren().add(new Label("Hello"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100); 
    secondaryStage.setScene(scene);
    secondaryStage.show();
}
```

Можете ознакомиться с другими примерами в английской версии: [JavaFX: can you create a stage that doesn't show on the task bar and is undecorated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564136/javafx-can-you-create-a-stage-that-doesnt-show-on-the-task-bar-and-is-undecora?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)